# Paypal Payment via Classic or Rest API

Tags: paypal, send, currency

I am a bit confused about the REST and Classic API and which one serves my business case best. My requirement is to be able to send money to one or many customers by just using their email addresses. No need to receive Payments, just to send...Additionally i do not want approvals, i just want to send the payment and the payment to be executed, since i am performing a receiver email validation via the getVerifiedStatus call.

I know there is the Mass Payment option and the Adaptive Payments option however for consistency i need to use only one API. Which API covers my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't yet covered well by PayPal's new REST APIs. But the MassPay api (with # of payments = a set, or just 1) can definitely do what you want. Check PayPal's handling of exception cases that is built into the MassPay product to ensure it meets your requirements; if it does then this is a great answer. The adaptive payments pay() can also definitely work; to determine which works for you will require evaluating the underlying PayPal products moreso than the APIs. They do NOT work entirely the same way....

Comment: Thank you geewiz for the answer! I am now considering the Adaptive Payments Pay API which can also use more than one receivers... Can you please clarify what u mean by "evaluating the underlying PayPal products"?Thanx

Comment: PayPal has many products to move money much like Honda has many products (cars) to move people. The products all share some core (money movement) but interfaces differ (apis & web pages etc) AND functionality also differs. E.g. MassPay has different fee structures than Adaptive Payments, different handling of attempted payments to email addresses that don't exist (or other issues that might arise), different limitations on funds you can send. It is like comparing an Accord to an Odyssey. Which is right for you depends on appearance (apis/integration) AND the different underlying capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to classic API for now as it's much more mature than the REST API is.  For your situation I'd go with Adaptive Payments, specifically the Pay API.  Since you are the app owner and the payer, you can simply trigger payments however you want to anybody you need.